# Why MouseMotionListener does not work?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I implement **MouseMotionListener**, also implement **MouseListener**. I added in constructor `newContentPane.addMouseListener(this)` and

```
newContentPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

It is not enough?
Methods like `mouseDragged(MouseEvent e),` `mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)` are not called.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BorderFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton northButton;
    private JButton southButton;
    private JButton westButton;
    private JButton eastButton;
    private JButton centerButton1;
    private JButton centerButton2;
    private JPanel newContentPane;
    private JSplitPane splitPane1;
    private JSplitPane splitPane2;

    public BorderFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        newContentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        northButton = new JButton("North");
        southButton = new JButton("South");
        westButton = new JButton("West");
        eastButton = new JButton("East");
        centerButton1 = new JButton("Center1");
        centerButton2 = new JButton("Center2");
        newContentPane.add(northButton, "North");
        newContentPane.add(southButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        newContentPane.add(westButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        newContentPane.add(eastButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        // newContentPane.add(centerButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        splitPane1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, centerButton1,
                centerButton2);
        splitPane1.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        splitPane1.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane1.setContinuousLayout(true);
        newContentPane.add(splitPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(newContentPane);
        newContentPane.addMouseListener(this);
        newContentPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    protected static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final BorderFrame borderFrame = new BorderFrame("Test BorderLayout");
        borderFrame.pack();
        borderFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        borderFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }


//AUTOGENERATED methods
....
}
```

Comment: `BorderFrame.java:12: error: BorderFrame is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(MouseEvent) in MouseListener`  Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of something that compiles, for a run-time problem..

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is completely filled with buttons that intercept mouse events. Replace one with a label to see the difference.

```
newContentPane.add(new JLabel("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Also consider using [`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and overriding just the methods you want to use.

```
MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
newContentPane.addMouseListener(handler);
newContentPane.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
…
private static class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the method of MouseMotionListener and MouseListener interfaces. Tere will be total 7 methods from both these interfaces that you need to override. Write code in those method which events you want to handle. But you need to override all these methods.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
   //Code what you want to do
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
   //Code what you want to do
}

 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
   //Code what you want to do
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
   //Code what you want to do
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
   //Code what you want to do
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
   //Code what you want to do
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   //Code what you want to do
}
```

Comment: I implement it, but only not attach it to this sample to save space, for example 
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
     System.out.printf("mouse %d %d \n", e.getX(), e.getY());

    }

Comment: You have registered newCOntentPane for this events. Doing something with mouse in this panel should execute corresponding method.

Comment: Make sure you are moving mouse in `newContentPane` only. You are adding `splitPane1` to  `newContentPane`. I am suspecting you are moving mouse in that panel. Try to register `splitPane1` for these events.

Comment: I add splitPane1.addMouseMotionListener(this), but works only if splitPanel is maximally on left or right, not when I adjust button sizes

Comment: Basically control that your layout have organized are not the way you expect. Neither your `newContentPane` is displayed it's hidden under your some controls. Organize your UI and make sure everything is displayed.

Comment: Why not `java.awt.event.MouseAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

if your frame contains only newContentPane (which contains other components) you can try just to add listeners to frame:

```
...
add(newContentPane);
addMouseListener(this);
addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
...
```